# How does backslash affect curly braces in regex?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

So I started to learn *regex* using `grep` and `sed` in linux, and I don't understand why I have to save curly braces? So saving means escaping characters to match them literally, but when I type in `grep 'test{2}'` it will only match `test{2}` and when I type `'test\{2\}'` it will match `testtest`. It's okay, but why backslash has another usage with other modifiers? For example in the case of `.` (dot), when I type `test.` it will match any text with test followed by any characters. In this case we need backslash to interpret it as a character. So when I use it like that: `test\.` it will only match `test.`

So summarized: why in the case of `{` backslash saves the curly braces to be interpreted as a character, and in the case of other modifiers, like `.` backslash saves the character to be interpreted as a special one...

I know it sounds hilarious but I don't understand it...

Comment: You should read about BRE POSIX regex standard and its difference from POSIX ERE.

Comment: Also, `test\{2\}` matches just the `testt` part of `testtest`. Try using `grep --color=always` to highlight the matched substrings.

Comment: Read the POSIX BRE and ERE specs at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html and the GNU grep and GNU sed man pages for how they use BREs and EREs (and for GNU grep PCREs which you can google if you care to delve into that).

Comment: It's not "hilarious".  It's a source of mass confusion!  Short explanation: over the course of time, there have been many different flavors of regex.  The syntax evolved, and 2 primary dialects survived.

Answer (score 1):

When `grep` is used with no `-E` you need to escape ("save") braces that are quantifiers because the regex flavor used is **POSIX BRE**:

```
grep 'test\{2\}' file # => Finds lines having testt, not testtest
```

and

```
grep '\(test\)\{2\}' file # => Finds lines having testtest
```

The identical **POSIX ERE** variants are

```
grep -E 'test{2}' file
grep -E '(test){2}' file
```

Another example is to match curly braces:

```
grep '{2}' file # => matches lines having {2} in them
grep -E '\{2}' file => same, note the } is not special
```

See [more about BRE and ERE POSIX regex standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

The differences between BRE and ERE POSIX syntax are just historical, there seems no specific idea behind that.